# R ggplot geom_boxplot groups of data and LABEL quartiles (hinges,whiskers)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I am plotting some data of water metal levels where I report the 90% to the MI-DEQ. I have boxplots of each of the metals and I want to label the hinge and whisker values. I've done something similar in base R for discrete data sets. Here is my starting code:

```
ggplot(data = Agm, aes(x = Street, y = Level) , na.rm=TRUE) +
  ggtitle("Lead Levels",subtitle=subtext )+
  xlab("Streets") + ylab("ppb") +
  geom_boxplot( fill="red",width = 0.8) + theme_bw()
```

Agm is a subsetted df with Street being chr and Level being numeric. How would I label each of the groups quantiles? Also, how would I have geom_boxplot whisker the max value, ie include outliers? If I create a df with the Street and quantile(0.9) for each street. Then how would I have `geom_point` plot and label over the above boxplot using the same grouping?

The data looks like this:

```
Agm<-read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 Street  Year  Month     Person     Level Metal
 Crawford 2019 June      RCR        0.13  Ag
 Crawford 2019 June      RCR        160   Cu
 Crawford 2019 June      RAR        0.92  Ag
 Crawford 2019 June      RAR        140   Cu
 Gratiot  2019 June      RL         NA    Ag
 Gratiot  2019 June      RL         24    Cu
 Seneca   2019 June      DS         0.33  Ag
 Seneca   2019 June      DS         75    Cu")
```

Sorry for the delay but I observe on my iPad but my R work is on my Linux box which was not readily available. The data is more expansive and will be growing.
This brings up another issue: the reporting metric is the 90 percentile. Is there a way to plot that point from the `geom_boxplot` call? This way each group would have the hinge and whisker values labeled as well as the 90 percentile.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including the dataset `Agm` in the question as a data frame object or use `dput(Agm)`. If `Agm` is large provide a subset which illustrates the problem have a look at [mre]

Comment: Thank you for your time and interest. My question is more general. How do I add the numeric value labels to the elements (whiskers, hinges, quantiles, etc) of a ggplot boxplot with factors that include multiple groups (each  metal was tested for 3 times so far, so the plot has 3 groups). I’ll post some data later.

Comment: Looking forward to the data; it's much easier to answer a question with a relevant dataset as it avoids misunderstanding.